# What's the meaning of "step high"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Below is a passage from [this](http://www.salon.com/2011/11/20/diary_of_a_porn_store_clerk/) article:

> The next day I trip over the writer’s wet dream and worst nightmare, the content farm. After some quick math, I figure that five pages of “How to Ride a Bicycle in Ankara” and “Grinding Coffee Beans for Small Business Owners” would pay as much as a day at the booths. It doesn’t take much to convince me to quit. **Stepping high**, I walk into my boss’s office, dropping my resignation letter on his desk. I spend my last two weeks nearly dancing around the booths...

What does *stepping high* mentioned above mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the context and the story leading up to that point, I believe the author was cleverly using a phrase that could mean several things:

1) ['High-stepping'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high-stepping) suggests the pursuit of pleasure.  He is looking forward to quitting his miserable job and the thought makes him downright giddy.

2) ['Walking tall'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/walk+tall) has a similar ring and would also fit here.  He is recovering his dignity and pride by turning in his resignation.

3) 'Stepping high' could also refer to his gait as he wades through the mess where he works, so as to not get anything on himself.

HTH